# Count Control structures

Tags: java, counting, control-structure

I want to count the used control structures (IF - statmens, switch case,..) in a simple Java class and simply save the amount in a variable.

Do you guys have an idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your question correctly, this is about pattern reading from a text file.

If you just want to have a program to check on another piece of code, you can read the .java as were to read a text file.

As you encounter words like `if` or `switch` add one to your variable.

Of course, you would want to ensure you are not reading in the commented lines
(I.e. ignore those after `//` and not within `/* */`)

---

**So how do you do that?**

You can read in the lines of code as a `String`, make use of String methods like `contains` or even make use of regex in Java to check whether that string contains the word you look for.

You can also take note of characters like `;` to help determine the end of a statement in the code.

Comment: The idea is to generate a random graph with a random amount of nodes and a random definition of edges between those nodes. Those nodes have and amount of control structures which are used during the runtime. What I want is to have an Interpreter class which counts the amount of used control structures (e.g. If-statements,..) within each node and therefore within a graph. The purpose is that i can save the amount of used e.g. If-statements, switch-case operations and so on for a further purpose.

Comment: So your graph will be generated by another piece of java code. After generating the graph, the calculation may involve x number of conditional checks (depending on the number of edges on the graph). You are interested in writing code to count number of these conditional checks? Is this what you were saying? By the way, what do you mean by interpreter class?

Comment: After the graph was generated, the programm will go through the graph structure. If a node has more than one edge it will choose an edge via a random function. Depending on how many edges a node has, it has more or less if statements which has to be checked. So when I got your question correct regarding the conditional checks, then yes I want to write code which counts those checks. The interpreter class simply adds all these checks together and checks how long the whole process lasts. But that class isn't that important for that question ^^

Answer (score 0):

In general, the information about your source structure will not be preserved in your runtime class.  The compiler may change it around, optimize it, add to it, etc, etc.

If you really mean lexical analysis of the source file, and not the class, there are a few packages available to help you do that - but you have to pass the source into them, and the results will not (up to O() notation) reflect the runtime values of these counts.